# Similar venues with location foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

I am playing with Foursquare API and I was wondering if theres an endpoint for getting a similar venue in a location given another venue?

All I found is this endpoint:

> https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/similar

Which returns a list of venues similar to a given venue. What I want is, exactly this but I want the returned venues be close to a given location.

For example:
I love a mexican restaurant in London.
I want to find a similar restaurant but in Barcelona.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [venues/similar](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/similar) endpoint will only show similar venues near the desired venue. Your best bet is probably using the `query` parameter with [venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore). The `query` parameter is pretty smart about determining your intent if you know what you're looking for and you can specify any location.

i.e.

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?
query=Mexican food outdoor seating
near=Barcelona
```